# Which necessary directory and files to be display to Android Application User?

Tags: android, filesystems, android-file

---

1. I want to know the Directory structure of Android.
2. Which is the necessary Android directory & files to be display to Android User and which is not ?
3. What if we have to show data of Android phone memory or what if data of sdcard or external memory ?

---

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Android runs on Linux, the file structure is very similar
2. It depends what you are trying to display. Most of the information you need can be accessed through Android's API's, however.
3. Phone memory can be accessed through various API's, such as [CallLog.Calls](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.Calls.html). External storage can be accessed as well, you can read more [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#AccessingExtFiles).